# google-maps-services-javascript search nearby places

Tags: node.js, google-maps

I just started to experiment with the google APIs and I was trying to retrieve all the places near me, by type.
https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js
It works perfectly, if I specify just one type. Ex type: 'museum'.

How I can retrieve results by multiple types?
https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In googlemaps documentation it specifies

> type — Restricts the results to places matching the specified type. Only one type may be specified (if more than one type is provided, all types following the first entry are ignored). See the list of supported types.

So, you might have to do multiple api calls and process the results.

`Promise.each([types].map(hitGooglemapsApi));`